# Did any one know about Appium Mobile Testing ... could please the explain process

Tags: appium

Appium is an open source mobile automation tool for iOS and Android. Appium can test native and hybrid applications, and can even be used to automate Mobile Safari on iOS.

Comment: Please post if you face any issues while automating using Appium! What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

please start from here - http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.3.4/?java#about-appium . This is very helpful and you will catch up very quickly